# How to display primary member list with the secondary member details

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter, I issue is regarding MySQL query.
I have two table which is member and relation.

**Member table**

What I am doing is, I am adding the all the user in the member table according to the `member_type`. If member_type is 1 then that is a primary member if 2 then a secondary member

[image]

**Relation table**

In the relation table, I am defining the relation of the user. For example `primary_member_id` is 1 then secondary members are 3 and 6 and secondary member details are available in the member table.

[image]

Now I need a query to display the all the primary member in the list and related to their secondary member name and other details.

I am using data table with a child row. so that I can display the primary name in the list and on click to the plus sign to display secondary member.

I tried below join code.

```
SELECT * FROM `member` LEFT JOIN relation on member.id=relation.primary_member_id WHERE member.member_type=1
```

below is the output of the above query. In this, I am getting the primary member name twice and how to display the secondary member name
[image]

I need an output

[image]

**data table**

```
     function format ( d ) {
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Mobile number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.phone+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'      
    '</table>';
}
$(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable =$('#all_list').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                // "serverSide": true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": baseUrl+ "/index.php/Search/Listdetails_ajax",
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "columns": [
                   {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                { "data": "profile_pic","className":"img_list_pic",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<img src='+baseUrl+'/uploads/images/'+data+' class="search_pic">';
                }
                 },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "phone" }
            ],
               "order": [[1, 'asc']],


            } );
    $('#all_list tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = oTable.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );

} );
```

**ajax**

```
public function Listdetails_ajax(){  
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $books = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_primary();
    $books_of_secondary = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_secondary();

    $data['draw'] = 1;
    $data['recordsTotal'] = count($books);
    $data['recordsFiltered'] = count($books);
    foreach ($books as $key => $row) 
    {
        $arr_result = array(
                   "profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                   "name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                    "phone" => $row->phone
        );
        $data['data'][] = $arr_result;
      }
      //print_r($arr_result);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

/*model*/

```
public function getTotalList_of_primary(){
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('member');
      $this->db->where('member_type',1);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $res   = $query->result();        
     return $res;
}

public function getTotalList_of_secondary(){
    /*what query I have to use here*/
}
```

Comment: Added answer to this question

Comment: @Adder, Can you help me out in below question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216064/how-to-send-the-tabs-input-fields-value-to-the-controller  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574228/what-is-the-best-and-fast-way-to-insert-data-in-multiple-tables-and-how-to-use-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the idea of using a details popup as seen in [details row](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), the controller would look like this:

```
public function Listdetails_ajax(){  
   $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $books = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_primary();

    $data['draw'] = 1;
    $data['recordsTotal'] = count($books);
    $data['recordsFiltered'] = count($books);
    foreach ($books as $key => $row) 
    {
        //print_r($row->customer_id);
        $arr_result = array(
                    "member_id" => base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->member_id)),
                    "profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                    "name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                    "phone" => $row->phone,
                    "chss_no" => $row->chss_no,
                    "emp_id" => $row->emp_id,
                    "address" => $row->address
                    // "member_type" => $row->member_type
        );

         $array_secondary = array();
         $books_of_secondary = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_secondary($row->customer_id);
         foreach ($books_of_secondary as $key => $row) 
            {
                //print_r($row->customer_id);
                $arr_result2 = array(
                            "s_member_id" => base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->member_id)),
                            "s_profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                            "s_name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                            "s_phone" => $row->phone,
                            "s_chss_no" => $row->chss_no,
                            "s_emp_id" => $row->emp_id,
                            "s_address" => $row->address
                );


                $array_secondary[] = $arr_result2;
            }
         $arr_result['secondary'] =  $array_secondary;  
         $data['data'][] = $arr_result;
      }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

And then in the format function you would access the `secondary` field to get an array of secondaries. Maybe like this:

```
function format(d) {
    // d is the original data object for the row var val;
    if(d.secondary.length == 0) {
        return "There are no secondary members";
    }

    var display = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'; 
    for (val of d.secondary) { 
        display += '<tr>' + '<td>Full name:</td>' + '<td>' + val.s_name + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + '<td>Mobile number:</td>' + '<td>' + val.s_phone + '</td>' + '</tr>';
    }
    display += '</table>';
    return display;
}
```

Comment: Get a user name other than `user...`, so people can recognize you when you visit again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two queries to achieve it.

First to get all primary members to display primary member list.

```
select * from Member m where m.member_type = 1;
```

Second to get all secondary members for that primary member id.

```
select * from Member m
join Relation r where m.member_id = r.secondary_member_id and 
r.primary_member_id = :primaryMemberId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, give me a time to implement this.

Comment: I am confused in the your second query. are you talking about link this? select * from member m
join relation r where m.id = r.secondary_member_id and 
r.primary_member_id = m.id

Comment: how to identify  :primaryMemberId;?

Comment: primaryMemberId is dynamic parameter to your second query. It should be obtained from your first query.
So, basically once you have a primary members list and you click one primary member to get its secondary members, then you want to pass that selected primary member's id in second query.

Comment: but how can I use that query with CodeIgniter?

Comment: In your second function "getTotalList_of_secondary", you need to use $this->db->where(primary_member_id, id) and pass each id within these iteration foreach ($books as $key => $row) .
For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood your last comment. are you talking about like this public function getTotalList_of_secondary(){
    $this->db->where('primary_member_id', 'id')
}

Comment: Yes. Your second function should have something like ::
$this->db->select('m.*,r.*');
$this->db->from('Member m');
$this->db->join('Relation r', 'r.secondary_member_id = m.member_id');
$this->db->where('r.primary_member_id',id);

Comment: but how $this->db->where('r.primary_member_id',id); id value will get in this where clause?

Comment: It should be your $row->id that you obtain in for loop where you iterate over books.

Comment: Trust me I am totally confused, Can you share the whole code? Please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174234/discussion-between-skelwa-and-user9437856).

Comment: any other help in this?