# What is the best and fast way to insert data in multiple tables and how to use Xss_Clean() for multiple an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeginator, I have three table (It will increase in the future according to requirement) and tables name are `"tbl_customer", "tbl_customer_billing","tbl_customer_shipping"`. Each table is connected with primary key and foreign key.

Now I am inserting the data in each table so I tried below code.

My question is:

1) Should I use `$this->security->xss_clean()` for each array? or any other idea to use only a single `xss_clean`?

2) What is the best and fast way to insert the data in the multiple tables?

I tried below code. Is it fine or should I use something another way?
I tried below code but there are lots of changes to lose the data. Is there any other idea?

Controller:

```
public function add_newcustomer(){
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_firstname', 'Firstname', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_lastname', 'Lastname', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_mobileno', 'Mobile no', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_billing_address', 'Billing Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_b_country', 'Country', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_b_state', 'State', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_b_city', 'City', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_b_zipcode', 'Zip code', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_shopping_address', 'Shopping Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_s_country', 'Country', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_s_state', 'State', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_s_city', 'City', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_s_zipcode', 'Zip code', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                $data['get_country']=$this->Customer_model->get_country();// all country name
                $this->load->view('create_order',$data);
                 }
                 else
                {
        $cust_personal = array(
                'c_firstname'=>$this->input->post('c_firstname'),
                'c_middlename'=>$this->input->post('c_middlename'),
                'c_lastname'=>$this->input->post('c_lastname'),
                'c_email_id'=>$this->input->post('c_email'),
                'c_mobileno'=>$this->input->post('c_mobileno'),
                'c_alternetno'=>$this->input->post('c_alternetno'),
                'c_created_by_emp'=>$this->session->userdata['login_session']['id'],
                'c_date_of_added'=>$this->current_date
                 );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_customer',$cust_personal);
            $last_cust_id= $this->db->insert_id();


        $cust_billing = array(
                'c_b_address'=>$this->input->post('c_billing_address'),
                'c_b_country'=>$this->input->post('c_b_country'),
                'c_b_state'=>$this->input->post('c_b_state'),
                'c_b_city'=>$this->input->post('c_b_city'),
                'c_b_zipcode'=>$this->input->post('c_b_zipcode'),
                'cust_id'=>$last_cust_id,
                'c_date_of_added'=>$this->current_date
            );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_customer_billing',$cust_billing);
            $last_billing_id= $this->db->insert_id();

         $cust_shipping = array(

                'c_s_address '=>$this->input->post('c_shopping_address'),
                'c_s_country'=>$this->input->post('c_s_country'),
                'c_s_state'=>$this->input->post('c_s_state'),
                'c_s_city'=>$this->input->post('c_s_city'),
                'c_s_zipcode'=>$this->input->post('c_s_zipcode'),
                'c_s_receiver_no'=>$this->input->post('c_receiver_no'),
                'cust_id'=>$last_cust_id,
                'c_billing_id'=>$last_billing_id,
                'c_date_of_added'=>$this->current_date
            );

            $this->db->insert('tbl_customer_shipping',$cust_shipping);

            redirect("Customer_control/index");

                }
}
```

Comment: No need to use $this->security->xss_clean(); for post array , Use instead `$this->input->post('some_data', TRUE);`  The second optional parameter lets you run the data through the XSS filter.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, There was some power issue at my home. Now i have to use use something like  'c_firstname'=>$this->input->post('c_firstname', TRUE). right?

Comment: @pradeep, Can you suggested me for inserting the data in multiple tables with fast and best way?

Comment: this is right approach to use like this `$this->input->post('c_firstname', TRUE);`. As far as inserting data into multiple table, what else could be better than the approach u r using, but make sure data is inserting properly by doing check for empty or blank etc

Comment: @pradeep, I added the client side validation using Jquery and server-side validation as well which is in the above code. I just want to know that am I on the right path to insert the data in multiple tables?

Comment: yes of course u r doing correct

Comment: @pradeep, Sounds good!! thanks

Comment: you could use transactions but it will also work this way. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html